# Extracting links from HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, html-parsing

i have to basically make a program that take a user-input web address and parses html to find links . then stores all the links in another HTML file in a certain format. i only have access to builtin python modules (python 3) . im able to get the HTML code from the link using urllib.request and put that into a string. how would i actually go about extracting links from this string and putting them into a string array? also would it be possible to identify links (such as an image link / mp3 link) so i can put them into different arrays (then i could catagorize them when im creating the output file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [re](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html) module to parse the HTML text for links. Particularly the `findall` method can return every match.

As far as sorting by file type that depends on whether the url actually contains the extension (i.e. .mp3, .js, .jpeg, etc...)

You could do a simple for loop like such:

```
import re
html = getHTMLText()
mp3s = []
other = []
for match in re.findall('<reexpression>',html):
    if match.endswith('.mp3'):
        mp3s.append(match)
    else:
        other.append(match)
```

Comment: yeah i had to take a crash course in regex but this worked :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use HTML.Parser library or re library
they will help you to do that 
and i think you can use regex to do it

> r'http[s]?://[^\s<>"]+|www.[^\s<>"]+